# Gradle error in Android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, synchronization

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

['com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDm54.png)

Comment: your gradle needs to be synced. then it'll continue throwing that red squiggly line. think of it as a notice that there's an update to that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you sync your gradle (use the 'Sync Now'), you shouldn't have any problems, this is just a warning.

If, however, you want to get rid of this warning, you'll have to manually change the versions of your dependencies. As stated in the warning,  you are using three different versions in similar dependencies. You should pick one version (usually the newest) and use it.